# Swift how to retrieve root child using `.ChildAdded`

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to retrieve `receiverId` from a firebase database (JSON below). I know how to complete this using `.Value` but I'm having dificulty with using `.ChildAdded`.

```
let postKey = "-KSJiJjUeuDQLZ7TsWAZ"
 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("version_one/frontEnd/post/\(postKey)").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {snapshot in

            print(snapshot)

})
```

When I retrieve using `.ChildAdded` I get

`Snap (postDescription) My car broke down 
Snap (postTitle) I need a ride tot the store
Snap (receiverId) 70SOFFoklaS6xiZI9i9S3UswXuf2
Snap (senderId) HKLJ72JgNOZRP6fnOvmyow5jwbA2
Snap (status) 0`

Im not sure how to get into the `Snap` to use `receiverId` tot get `70SOFFoklaS6xiZI9i9S3UswXuf2`

```
{
  "version_one" : {
    "frontEnd" : {
      "post" : {
        "-KSJiJjUeuDQLZ7TsWAZ" : {
          "postDescription" : "My car broke down ",
          "postTitle" : "I need a ride tot the store",
          "receiverId" : "70SOFFoklaS6xiZI9i9S3UswXuf2",
          "senderId" : "HKLJ72JgNOZRP6fnOvmyow5jwbA2",
          "status" : 0
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
snapshot.child("receiverId").value as! String
```

This takes the `receiverId` child of the snapshot and then gets the string value from it.